# Visual Studio 2012: running unit tests with big time overhead / delay

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vs-unit-testing-framework

I just started a new project in C# using Visual Studio 2012. VS2012 is up-to-date, so there is no beta or RC installed. When I run my unit tests, there is a big delay. Test summary says, that it ran 10 seconds, and the 4 unit tests ran in summary 96ms. This is what Test Explorer tells me. Why is there such a big time overhead of nearly 10 seconds? It's obviously pretty annoying if you do TDD...

Is there any configuration setting I have to set? Did I miss something?

Or is it (still) a bug in VS2012? I found a blog regarding VS2012 BETA (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/03/08/what-s-new-in-visual-studio-11-beta-unit-testing.aspx). At the end of that article, they say following: "Unit Test Startup Performance – Right now we have a pretty ugly delay after you start a test run and we are aggressively working to make that go away." But I didn't find anything more about that problem. Maybe the bug is still present.

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short update: two workmates can reproduce this.

Comment: again an update: It seems that someone has a similar problem, reported on a forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstest/thread/604fc9c1-06d8-4019-a5cc-12c3a926ad5f/

Comment: In the past week I've noticed this same issue/delay at my company. Try disabling your network card and running your tests. I discovered that when I did this my tests ran instantly. It turned out to be an issue with my VPN. If I disable my VPN and run the tests they run instantly. I don't know why VS tries connecting to the internet prior to running tests but when that happens, and it happens over my VPN, the causes a big delay before running my unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

In the upcoming Visual Studio quarterly release (ref http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/08/visual-studio-2012-update-1-ctp.aspx), we have made some performance improvements.  In short, we changed the underlying storage mechanism to improve the discovery/run time.

Please download the quarterly release when it becomes available. Also, please let us know if you have more issues.

Regards,

Patrick Tseng, Visual Studio ALM team.